# How to enter percentage values in a cell

Tags: c#, winforms, c1flexgrid

We have an unbound **C1FlexGrid**.

We are displaying percent figures as follows:

```
grid.Format = "#,##0.00%"
```

So far this works. If the cell value is **0.8**, then the grid displays **80%**

But we are stuck with the input.
We want that the users can just enter "80" (without entering the % sign), the but the grid should store "0.8"

Is that somehow possible? I messed around with the **EditMask** property, but found no solution.

Comment: What happens if they choose to enter 0.8?

Answer (score 1):

Mask the input to take just the integer andyou can place a seperate % sign as a label. Then in the code convert the sting to float and divide it by 100